# Why doesn't window.open('//google.com', TARGET) reuse the same tab like other domains?

Tags: javascript

(**Edited because //google.com and //www.google.com were actually different domains.**)

`window.open(URL, 'TARGET')` normally creates a new tab named TARGET and keeps re-using this tab to open future calls to `window.open(URL, 'TARGET')`

However, if the URL is a Google domain, the existing tab is not used; new tabs are always created. This may have something to do with same origin policies, but other domains *will* reuse the TARGET tab. (I haven't found any other domains that behave like Google.)

So is Google doing something special to opt-in to this behavior where named tabs cannot be re-used?

---

Edited example:

```
// Open dev console on stackoverflow.com (to ensure cross-origin):

w = window.open('//google.com')  // Opens new tab.
w.closed                         // true, even though tab still open.

w = window.open('//apple.com')   // Opens new tab.
w.closed                         // false (like every other non-google domain)
```

- `window.open()` returns a `WindowProxy`, which is like a `Window` object.
- So `w.closed` is "a read-only property [that] indicates whether the referenced window is closed or not."

[image]

Comment: Same Origin Policy

Comment: @epascarello I don't think Same Origin Policy can be the whole story because window.open was called from the same google.com origin

Comment: `//www.google.com` is not the same origin as `//google.com`

Comment: @epascarello ah, you're right. How to explain difference in behavior between www.google.com and other domains though? Does the web site need to opt in somehow? *.google.com seems to be the only domain with this behavior (even cross domain)...

Comment: There is no opting in....

Comment: @epascarello: Interesting twist: `//www.apple.com` is not the same origin as `//apple.com`, either. Yet there is still a difference between apple.com and google.com